# What is electron-wrapped process?

Tags: ubuntu, process, wrap

I found this process today but I don't recognize it.
Searching i found that is a [tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-wrapper) but I haven't installed it.(directly)
Can it be a problem to consider?
Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) said this is probably an application like VSCode, Slack, Insomnia, Element, ...

Electron is a framework based on the Chrome Javascript Engine, to either run Websites/Webapplications in their own programs locally, or to just write an app in javascript/typescript.

It is, basically its own little browser.